PHP sessions not working properly in Codeigniter 4
PHP session are not working properly. Values in the session are first stored in  get_values_from_email(). But I cannot see the values of the var_dump($this->session->get()) inside the function change_password() printed on the screen. If I perform the var_dump($this->session->get()) at the beginning of the script then I am able to retrieve session the values.
At the end of the function change_password() the session $this->session->get('email') is always empty at the end of the function, but outputs the a value if I echo the session at the beginning of the function. I am a newbie here and I would like to know what I am doing wrong with sessions. Thanks!
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\Password_recovery_model;
use App\Validation;

class Password_recovery extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {  
       $this->session    = \Config\Services::session(); 
    
    
    }

public function index(){ 
                        return view('password_recovery');
                       }

public function get_values_from_email(){ 
                                        
// var_dump($this->session->get());
$uri             = new \CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI(current_url());
if(!empty($uri->getSegment(4)) && !empty($uri->getSegment(5))){ 

$email_code = $uri->getSegment(4);
$email      = $uri->getSegment(5);

//stored session values            
$this->session->set('email_code', $email_code); 
$this->session->set('email',$email);   
return view('change_password');                                                                                                                        
}   
}

public function change_password(){
                               
$request          = \Config\Services::request();
$userModel        = new Password_recovery_model();
$password_changed = false;

$password        =$request->getJsonVar('password');
$validation_code =$request->getJsonVar('validation_code');

$validation = \Config\Services::validation();

           
if(!$validation->withRequest($this->request)->run()){  
                                                
$val_arr_p=$validation->getErrors();


if(isset($val_arr_p['password'])&& !empty($val_arr_p['password'])){ 
                                                $data = array("error"=> $val_arr_p['password']);

                                                return  $this->response->setJSON($data);
                                                } 
// var_dump($this->session->get());

}else{ 
if(!empty($this->session->get('email'))){

 $email = $this->session->get('email');

 }


if(!empty($email)){                 
    //  $password_changed = $userModel->change_password($validation_code,$email,$password);

    $data             = array("message"=> "Su contraseña ha sido cambiada exitosamente");
    return  $this->response->setJSON($data); 

    }else{
        // $email =  $session->get('email');
        if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
                                        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                                            echo  $_SESSION['email_code'].$_SESSION['email'] ;


                                        }

            $data             = array("message"=> "No email variable222");

            return  $this->response->setJSON($data); 
            }

                            }


//confirmed email
if($password_changed){
$data   = array("message"=> "Su correo electrónico ha sido enviado exitosamente. Puede demorar hasta 5 minuton en llegar.");
}else{
$data = array("message"=> "Hubo un error porfavor trate de nuevo.");
}        

}

public function send_email_to_user_to_change_password(){
$request   = \Config\Services::request();
$email     =$request->getJsonVar('email');
$userModel = new Password_recovery_model();

if(!empty($email)){

                
//generates validation code  
$email_validation_code = $userModel->email_validation_code();

//sends code to email
$send_e = $userModel->send_email_to_change_password($email);
if($send_e){
        $data   = array("message"=> "Su correo electrónico ha sido enviado exitosamente para recuperar su contraseña. El mismo puede tardar hasta 5 minutos en llegar. ");
        return $this->response->setJSON($data);

        }
    else{ 
                $data   = array("message"=> "Hubo un problema. Trate nuevamente");
                return $this->response->setJSON($data);
            }
        }


}
public function pass_generator(){

$userModel = new Password_recovery_model();
$pgen      = $userModel->random_str();
$data      = array("gen_p"=> $pgen);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')->appendHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');

return $this->response->setJSON($data);

                                }
}
?>

I am expecting the $this->session->get('email') session variable to have a value.

You are initialising the session twice - first in the constructor, and then again in get_values_from_email() with $session = session();.  I haven't used sessions in CI4 but it seems a pretty good bet that this would cause problems?  Not the (current) problem but you are also initialising $validation twice, which seems another potential bug.  And view("change_password"); at the end of change_password() looks like another bug, missing return.

@mickmackusa How should I style my code to look better? Are there any examples I can refer to format the code better? Are there any tutorials in StackOverflow on how to style the code ?

Maybe try searching?  Any of "PHP code style",  "code formatting", "php style guide" will get you plenty of examples, guides, and tools to get started, eg https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/.  Any IDE you are using will format your code for you.  You could also simply browse any large, popular PHP project sources (for eg Codeigniter, you already have that code locally on disk).

It is very hard to read, but the most recent edit you made seems to have significantly changed your code, including fixes for some (all?) of the bugs I described in my comment?  But you haven't mentioned anything about these changes ...?  It is hard to help with a question that keeps changing.  If the problem is still the same, maybe it is related to how the browser gets between these methods, ie your routes and the form.

AFAICT 90% of the code here is probably not relevant, if you're having trouble with sessions you could check that with 2x 1-line methods - 1 line to set a session var, and 2nd line to read it. Taking some time to create a minimal example which demonstrates the problem might help you and others solve it much faster.

Declare a variable above the constructor to use the service, but this service already exists by default in the BaseController
class Password_recovery extends BaseController
{

public $session;

    public function __construct()
    {  
       $this->session    = \Config\Services::session();    
    
    }
}

